# Raspberry Pi 2 / Python + Mutliple Senors output?

Tags: python, sensors, pyserial, raspberry-pi2

I'm new to coding/Python an I'm working on some code that will take the values from two Atlas Scientific Sensors (temperature and dissolved oxygen) and write them to a text file along with a timestamp using a Raspberry Pi Model2.
So far this is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial
import datetime
import time

###Sensor serial settings
temp = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
tempser = serial.Serial(temp, 9600)
do = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
doser = serial.Serial(do, 9600)

###Temperature Sensor Settings
tempser.write("SF\r")

###DOSensor Settings
doser.write("C,1\r")

###Looop
line = ""
line2 = ""

while True:
    dodata = doser.read()
    tempdata = tempser.read()
    f=open('2Sensor.txt','a')
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp = date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
    outstring = str(timestamp)+" "+line
    outstring2 = " "+line2+"\n"

    if(dodata == "\r"):
            print timestamp +" D.O. "+line
            f.write(outstring)
            line = ""

    else:
            line = line + dodata

    if(tempdata == "\r"):           
            print timestamp +" Temp "+line2
            f.write(outstring2)
            line2 = ""

    else:
            line2 = line2 + tempdata
```

the teminal output looks like this:

```
2015/08/26 14:08 D.O. 8.42
2015/08/26 14:08 Temp 84.38
2015/08/26 14:08 D.O. 8.42
2015/08/26 14:08 Temp 84.39
```

and writes to a text file like this:

```
2015/08/26 13:47 8.42 84.45
2015/08/26 13:48 8.43 84.47
2015/08/26 13:48 8.42 84.47
2015/08/26 13:48 8.42 84.45
2015/08/26 13:49 8.422015/08/26 13:49 8.42 84.45
2015/08/26 13:50 8.42 84.45
2015/08/26 13:50 8.42 84.47
2015/08/26 13:50 8.43 84.47
2015/08/26 13:51 8.43 84.47
2015/08/26 13:51 8.432015/08/26 13:52 8.43 84.45
2015/08/26 13:52 8.43 84.47
```

Why can I not get the terminal output to have the values from both sensors on one line and why does it double up in the text file every five readings?
I have tried many different changes from googling but what I have posted here got me closest to my goals.
Any help or tips  would be appreciated.

Info on the sensors

[Do Sensor](http://www.atlas-scientific.com/_files/_datasheets/_circuit/DO_EZO_Datasheet.pdf?)

[Temp](http://www.atlas-scientific.com/_files/_datasheets/_probe/ENV-TEMP-D.pdf)

Thanks!

**Here is the final code with Manuel Wong's mods and my tweaks:**

```
import serial
import datetime
import time

###Sensor serial settings
temp = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
tempser = serial.Serial(temp, 9600)
do = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
doser = serial.Serial(do, 9600)

###Temperature Sensor Settings
tempser.write("SF\r")

###DOSensor Settings
doser.write("C,1\r")

###Looop
line = "" 
line2 = ""
lineout = ""

while True:
    dodata = doser.read()
    tempdata = tempser.read()
    f=open('2Sensor.txt','a')
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp = date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")

    if (dodata == "\r"):
        lineout = " D.O. " + line
        line = ""

    else:
        line = line + dodata

    if(tempdata == "\r"):           
        lineout = lineout + " Temp "+line2
        line2 = ""

    else:
        line2 = line2 + tempdata

    if len(lineout) >= 20:
        print timestamp + lineout  
        f.write(timestamp + lineout)
        lineout = ""

        time.sleep(360)
```

Comment: You might be reading faster than the sensor's output rate. Try blocking reads by a minimum number of characters: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects . Printing to a terminal is much slower than just writing to a file, which explains why it behaves differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is aobut synchronization. Since you are using a serial port to read the sensor, you read one character at a time and you get the whole reading after you find the character "\r".  Sometimes you find that both readings (tempser and doser) are completed and that's why you find two readings in a line in your file.  You can try to print your data every time you find your reading is completed.

```
import serial
import datetime
import time

###Sensor serial settings
temp = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
tempser = serial.Serial(temp, 9600)
do = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
doser = serial.Serial(do, 9600)

###Temperature Sensor Settings
tempser.write("SF\r")

###DOSensor Settings
doser.write("C,1\r")

###Looop
line = "" 
line2 = ""
lineout = ""

while True:
    dodata = doser.read()
    tempdata = tempser.read()
    f=open('2Sensor.txt','a')
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp = date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
    outstring = str(timestamp)+" "+line
    outstring2 = " "+line2+"\n"

    if (dodata == "\r"):
        lineout = " D.O. " + line
        f.write(outstring)
        line = ""

    else:
        line = line + dodata

    if(tempdata == "\r"):           
        lineout = lineout + " Temp "+line2
        f.write(outstring2)
        line2 = ""

    else:
        line2 = line2 + tempdata

    if len(lineout) != 0:
        print timestamp + lineout  
#       optional if you want to print the same result to a file uncomment the next line and remove the previous f.write instructions
#       f.write(timestamp + lineout)
        lineout = ""
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked with just a little tweak. Your mod still gave me the the single reading and a reading with both sensors every 5  lines or so. I just added `if len(lineout) >=20:`  So that it would print only the reading that had both of the sensors. Now it works like I want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are printing the values with 2 print instructions.  Every print generate a line. Try to print the data when you have both values of your reading. About the duplicate lines, clear variables line and line2 in every iteration on the loop.

Comment: So I tried    `while True:
    dodata = doser.read()
    tempdata = tempser.read()
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp = date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")

    if dodata == "\r" and tempdata == "\r":
            print timestamp +"  "+line
            line = ""

    else:
            line = line + dodata + tempdata` But it didn't get the output right. Any other suggestions?